Angular, How to specify a parent component only takes an array of child components of certain type
In Angular, I want to create my own  component, which will take an array of  components, looks like this
<tab-group>
   <tab label='tab 1'>tab 1 content</tab>
   <tab label='tab 2'>tab 2 content</tab>
<tab-group> 

question: how do I specify that  only takes an array of 's?
